# Get Raw data from bcypt hash

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I am saving my password after hashing using `bcrypt` Now I need to get raw data from hash value.

suppose,
My password 123456. I am saving the password after hash suppose `3jhjhjkjk34k34k34j`

I need to get my password from the hash value.

Answer (score 2):

You don't decrypt passwords with bcrypt because it's a one-way algorithm. What you can do is provide the plaintext and the hash (from the database) and compare.

Example:

```
const passwordEnteredByUser = "123456"
const hash = "HASH_STRING"

bcrypt.compare(passwordEnteredByUser, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  } else if (!isMatch) {
    console.log("Password doesn't match!")
  } else {
    console.log("Password matches!")
  }
})
```

Comment: is there any way, I can get the percentage of matching/comparing value.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't get a percentage. For further reading on how bcrypt works, follow [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-in-action-understanding-bcrypt/)